# How do I find every element that is in both of two other lists?

Tags: python

Write a function commonElements(a1, a2) that takes in 2 tuples as arguments and returns a sorted tuple containing elements that are found in both tuples.

My task is :

```
    >>> commonElements((1, 2, 3), (2, 5, 1))
    (1, 2)
    >>> commonElements((1, 2, 3, 'p', 'n'), (2, 5 ,1, 'p'))
    (1, 2, 'p')
    >>> commonElements((1, 3, 'p', 'n'), ('a', 2 , 5, 1, 'p'))
    (1, 'p')
```

I tried to do it like this.

```
def commonElements(a1, a2):
    return tuple(set(a1).intersection( set(a2) ))
```

Anyone know what my mistake is with the requirement?
I can not pass.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. This seems to do what you're asking.

Comment: @Ben He thinks that too.  *That* is his problem, as someone else (his teacher?) deemed his answer incorrect.

Comment: This was a good example of how to ask a homework question, because you showed your attempt and asked about a specific issue. However please note that homework questions should be tagged as `homework`.

Comment: @John, fair 'nuff. I didn't notice the sort requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set is not ordered. So the order of the result may be arbitrary.
I would come up with something like that:

```
def commonElements(a1, a2):
    L = []
    for el in a1:
        if el in a2:
            L.append(el)
    return tuple(L)
```

Please, note, that this way of solving the problem would get the output elements ordered as in the tuple `a1`. So, as mentioned in the comments, the more correct way to call it is 'ordering', not 'sorting'.
Also, it has a complexity of `O(n*m)`, where `n` and `m` are the lengths of the lists `a1` and `a2` respectively.

`O(n*log(m))` can be achieved in this case if `bisect` module is used to access the elements of the second tuple `a2` (which should be sorted before the proceeding).

If sorting in common way is required, I would stick with your code, a bit altered:

```
def commonElements(a1, a2):
    return tuple(sorted(set(a1).intersection(set(a2))))
```

On the average it has a complexity of `O(min(m+n)*log(min(n+m)))` (because of sorting), and `O(n*m)` in the worst case because of [intersection](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

If the code needs to be implemented without using `set` (for example for the purposes of study), here is the code:

```
def commonElements(a1, a2):
    L = []
    for el in a1:
        if el in a2:
            L.append(el)
    L.sort()
    return tuple(L)
```

Complexity is `O(n*m)`.

With using `bisect` the code would look this way:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
def commonElements(a1, a2):
   L = []
   a2.sort() #sort a2 to be able to use binary search in the internal loop thus changing the complexity from O(n^2) to O(n*log(n)) (assuming n and m are rather equal).
   a2_len = len(a2)
   for el in a1:
       i = bisect_left(a2, el)
       if i != a2_len and a2[i] == el:
           L.append(x)
   # L.sort() #uncomment this line if the list in sorted order is needed (not just ordered as the first lits; it's possible to sort a1 in the very beginning of the function, but that would be slower on the average since L is smaller on the average than a1 or a2 (since L is their intersection).
   return tuple(L)
```

Complexity is `O(n*log(m))`.

Comment: This assumes that the tuples `a1` begins in sorted order. This is however the "good" `O(N)` way to do it as opposed to the intersect-and-then-sort method (which is good enough, only `O(N log(N))`), but you have state the very strong assumption that `a1` is sorted. This would still be incorrect per the original question, even with the "a1 must be sorted" assumption. Happy to remove -1 if caveat stated.

Comment: Oops! The result is supposed to be a tuple. I'll correct the code.

Comment: @ninjagecko Wouldn't it be O(N^2)? The `if el in a2` is itself a search, is it not?

Comment: @ninjagecko: If I understood the task correctly, the order should be kept as in the first tuple.

Comment: If 'to sort' meant to apply a traditional sorting, I would stick with a slightly corrected variant provided in the question: `return tuple(sorted(list(set(a1).intersection( set(a2)))))`

Comment: @ovgolovin: ah sorry, I had considered that, but chucked it up as "that couldn't be what was meant"; being the accepted answers seems to indicate you interpreted correctly. =)

Comment: Hmm.. depends if the OP has understood the requirements himself at this point. From the requirements, it sounds to me like the tuple should be sorted in the normal fashion, as opposed to ordered.

Comment: Yeah, I think it has O(m*n) complexity, since search is done for all m elements of a1, and for each element of a1 n/2 elements of a2 (on the average) are looked up.

Comment: He asked for sorted. Even if he really meant that to be "ordered like in first tuple", this accepted answer will be misleading to anyone else reading this question.

Answer (score 4):

```
def commonElements(a1, a2):
     return tuple(sorted(set(a1).intersection( set(a2) )))
```

Answer (score 3):

You've forgot the sorting requirement?

**EDIT**

Apparently, set sorts its elements in ascending order, but this is probably an implementation detail. If you were asked to write this function as a test, maybe you're required to implement the whole thing instead of delegating to set?

**EDIT 2**

For completeness, an implementation that should meet the requirements:

```
def commonElements(a1, a2):
    common = []
    for x in a1:
        if x in a2:
            common.append(x)
    common.sort()
    return tuple(common)
```

Answer (score 0):

The program seems to work for me. python-2.7.1+.

However, want to mention, that sets are by definition "Unordered".  Hence, the set resulting from the "intersection" will also be unordered.

TO get get a this into a tuple whose elements are ordered, needs additional code.

Probably something along the lines of

```
def commonElements(a1, a2):
    intersection = list(set(a1).intersection(set(a2)))
    intersection.sort()
    return tuple(intersection)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html,

Answer (score 0):

Another short example solution.  This is how I would write it.  Shortest solution?

```
def commonElements(a1, a2):
     return tuple(sorted([x for x in a1 if x in a2]))
```